# Render node or taxonomy term view depend on number of nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, taxonomy

I have taxonomy_menu module enabled and a lot of categories. Some terms has no nodes assigned, some terms has a lot of nodes. In first case, I display information that there is no content on this term. In second case, I display list of nodes.

But what if there is just one node assigned to given term? I would like to render node page. How can I do it? I can detect it in 
themename_preprocess_page
but what then? how render view page with term metatags and how render node with node metatags depend on term node count?